# Scheduler using Calendar class

Tags: java, calendar, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a Scheduler application where a user enter some information like a task name, time and date. The application should check every minute if there is a task at the current time, it will pop-up a window or make a sound. Now I am stuck with the checking process.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://Courses//PlannerText.txt"));

    final Runnable checker = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println( "This is time before if statement "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) +":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
            try {
                String line = null;
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) !=null) 
                {   
                     String[] currTask = line.split("\\|");

                     if (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)== Integer.parseInt(currTask[2])
                        && cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) == Integer.parseInt(currTask[3])){


                         System.out.println( "This is time after if statement "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) +":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
                         System.out.println("This is the time of the task "+currTask[3]+":"+currTask[2]);

                         JFrame reminderFrame = new JFrame("Reminder");
                         reminderFrame.setVisible(true);
                         reminderFrame.setLocation(200,200);
                     }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    final ScheduledFuture checkerHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(checker, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);   
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            checkerHandle.cancel(true);
        }
    }, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);   
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The frame doesn't pop-up when the current time = the task's time in the text file, so would anyone tell me what is the wrong with this piece of code  !!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where currTask[2] is the minute field in the text file,
and currTask[3] is the hour field in the text file.

Comment: It would be better if **you** told us what is wrong, and then **we** provide the solution...

Comment: Any reason to do this completely by hand? how about using something like cron4j?

Comment: @SJuan76 it doesn't work...it doesn't pop-up the frame when the current time = the time of the task in the text file.

Comment: @greedybuddha Its a task in school so I don't think they will like the idea of using a built-in scheduler.

Comment: We don't have the data file, we don't have complete source, we cannot tell from this what the problem is (or at least what all the problems might be).  SSCCE is needed - boil down the question to the least code that demonstrates the behavior you do not want, and ask a (more) specific question about it.  It helps if there is evidence of debugging attempts on your own -- have you put a println statement that prints every time the timer fires, at least one print statement that prints out the minute/second value in each line of your file?

Comment: 1st thanks for the tips, I added some printouts to the code, which is the whole code for this specific part. I change the data of the file manually and then run this code.I did print out the minute and hour field of the text file before and they were alright thats why I didn't mention something about the text file. Anyway I figured out that the code works fine for the first time I run it if the timing were the same; it pops up the frame and print out all of my statements. But each minute, it only prints out the one before the if statement, and doesn't go through the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the concept of debugging.  Place some debugging either a breakpoint or a printout to show the values of the currTask array.

Probably either you are using the wrong array index or the time is wrong (Maybe HOUR_OF_DAY)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did print out the values of the array before and they were alright. And I have just tried with HOUR_OF_DAY but it didn't make any difference. But I figured out that the code works fine for the first time I run it, of course if the timing were the same; it pops up the frame and print out all of my statements. But it doesn't do this each minute, it only prints out the one before the if statement, and doesn't go through the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone but I have figured it out...since my buffered reader was outside of my run() method, the file was being read only once when it starts and not every minute.